# Can someone help me with this vertex?

Tags: modeling, edges

I'm making a robot and that is the arm:
[image: Arm]

When i try to add a vertex with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and scale down, that happens:

[image: Arm 2]

What can I do so these vertex join all edges?

Comment: Can you please clarify your question. Firs off you have 4 vertices selected in every screen shot. So do you want to work with only one or all 4? What do you want to join the edges to? What did you want the scaling to do?

Comment: You have duplicate faces and when you cut you are only cutting one set of quads. Erase the surplus faces.

Answer (score 5):

It appears to be a duplicate vertices/faces issue. Basically, there are two (or more) vertices where there should be one, creating unwanted geometry.

This is the problem:

[image] [image]

The simplest solution is to select all of the vertices and to use the Remove Doubles option to automatically remove the overlapping geometry as show below:

[image]